# How to detect in Whatsapp-web.js when a number is typing or when it has received a number link and has clicked it

Tags: javascript, triggers, message

I need to trigger an event when a person has received the link of a bot.This bot is going to send a specific message but the event has to be when the person clicks a link, because this library has events like when the it is ready, when it receives a message. Please let me understand how to use this library because I am new to using javascript libraries. Of course I already made the connection and it is recieving messages pretty well.

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

const client = new Client();

 client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    // Generate and scan this code with your phone
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
   });

  client.on('ready', () => {
     console.log('Client is ready!');
  });

  client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.body == '!ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
  }
  });

  client.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really understand your questions, but try my best to answer it. Whatsapp-web.js is a client js library to help expose the api and events in web whatsapp. As the example code in your question, a message event will be given out once there is a new message. The message content is in the msg variable in your code. If you want to detect if there is a link in the message, you can write code like this (this a sudo code, you have to complete it in JS by yourself):

```js
  client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.body.indexOf("http") != -1) {
    //check if there is a link in the msg
    //there is a link in the message
    console.log(msg.body)
  }
  });
```

For more information, [this post](https://jmsliu.com/4771/study-js-apis-and-event-in-web-whatsapp.html) may help.